# How to use Laravel eloquent to select subquery and do UNION?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `counts`

```
id | location_id | count | created_at  
1 | 25 | 34 | 2020-12-28 02:11:01  
2 | 25 | 23 | 2020-12-28 04:11:01
```

Desired Output

```
hour | sumCount  
01:00 0  
02:00 34  
03:00 0  
04:00 23  
..  
..  
23:00 0
```

Raw SQL which works in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT
CONCAT(lpad(cast(HH as char(2)),2,'0'), ':00') as hour,  
  sum(count) as sumCount from
(
    SELECT
      EXTRACT(HOUR from created_at) AS HH,
      count
    FROM counts
    WHERE count > 0
    AND location_id = 25
    AND created_at >= '2021-01-01 0:0:0' and created_at < '2021-01-02 0:0:0'
    UNION ALL SELECT  0,0
    UNION ALL SELECT  1,0 UNION ALL SELECT  2,0  UNION ALL SELECT  3,0
    UNION ALL SELECT  4,0 UNION ALL SELECT  5,0  UNION ALL SELECT  6,0
    UNION ALL SELECT  7,0 UNION ALL SELECT  8,0 UNION ALL SELECT  9,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 10,0 UNION ALL SELECT 11,0 UNION ALL SELECT 12,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 13,0 UNION ALL SELECT 14,0 UNION ALL SELECT 15,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 16,0 UNION ALL SELECT 17,0 UNION ALL SELECT 18,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 19,0 UNION ALL SELECT 20,0 UNION ALL SELECT 21,0
    UNION ALL SELECT 22,0 UNION ALL SELECT 23,0
) as m
group by lpad(cast(HH as char(2)),2,'0')
```

My attempt in Helpers.php below but got Error
Call to a member function getBindings() on string

```
$sub = DB::table('counts')
            ->selectRaw('EXTRACT(HOUR from created_at) AS HH,
            count')
            ->where('count', '>', 0)
            ->where('location_id', $location_id)
            ->where("created_at >= '2021-01-01 0:0:0' and created_at < '2021-01-02 0:0:0'")
            ->union("UNION ALL SELECT  0,0
            UNION ALL SELECT  1,0 UNION ALL SELECT  2,0  UNION ALL SELECT  3,0
            UNION ALL SELECT  4,0 UNION ALL SELECT  5,0  UNION ALL SELECT  6,0
            UNION ALL SELECT  7,0 UNION ALL SELECT  8,0 UNION ALL SELECT  9,0
            UNION ALL SELECT 10,0 UNION ALL SELECT 11,0 UNION ALL SELECT 12,0
            UNION ALL SELECT 13,0 UNION ALL SELECT 14,0 UNION ALL SELECT 15,0
            UNION ALL SELECT 16,0 UNION ALL SELECT 17,0 UNION ALL SELECT 18,0
            UNION ALL SELECT 19,0 UNION ALL SELECT 20,0 UNION ALL SELECT 21,0
            UNION ALL SELECT 22,0 UNION ALL SELECT 23,0");

        $visitors_today_byHour = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()})"))
            ->mergeBindings($sub)
            ->selectRaw("lpad(cast(HH as char(2)),2,'0') as hour, sum(count) as sumCount")
            ->groupBy("lpad(cast(HH as char(2)),2,'0')")
            ->get();
```

Comment: Not Clear of your db table, can you please update it as table view so can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This should be the exact same query.

```php
$sub = DB::query()
        ->selectRaw(
                'extract(HOUR from created_at) as HH, '.
                'count'
        )
        ->from('counts')
        ->where('count', '>', 0)
        ->where('location_id', 25)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', '2021-01-01 0:0:0')
        ->where('created_at', '<', '2021-01-02 0:0:0')
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('0, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('1, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('2, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('3, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('4, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('5, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('6, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('7, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('8, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('9, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('10, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('11, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('12, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('13, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('14, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('15, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('16, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('17, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('18, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('19, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('20, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('21, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('22, 0'))
        ->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('23, 0'));

$query = DB::query()
        ->selectRaw(
                'concat(lpad(cast(HH as char(2)), 2, "0"), ":00") as hour, '.
                'sum(count) as sumCount'
        )
        ->from($sub, 'm')
        ->groupByRaw('lpad(cast(HH as char(2)), 2, "0")');

// $sql = $query->toSql();

$results = $query->get();
```

I suppose you could make it smaller by using a loop.

```
$sub = ... ->where('created_at', '<', '2021-01-02 0:0:0');

foreach (range(0, 23) as $i) { $sub->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw($i.', 0')); }
```